# How do I reach out to Microsoft Edge Add-ons support to enquire about certification failure of my extension package?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

I recently submitted my extension which was under review. But I received an email from Microsoft Edge extensions team that my submission was rejected because my product is not testable.

I want to share the testing steps and credentials with them to ensure that my product is successfully tested and published. How do I contact them to clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

After you submit your extension using Partner Center and you have questions about the review status or provide additional details for your product to be successfully tested, navigate to [New Support Request](https://support.microsoft.com/supportrequestform/e7a381be-9c9a-fafb-ed76-262bc93fd9e4) and complete the form.

You could also contact Microsoft Edge Add-ons support team to request help for any issues or submit feedback by following the steps provided in the [support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/contact-extensions-team).

Hope this information helps. Thank you!